# A good way to implement useable Callbacks in C++

Tags: c++, coding-style, callback

I have a custom Menu class written in C++. To seperate the code into easy-to-read functions I am using Callbacks.

Since I don't want to use Singletons for the Host of the Menu I provide another parameter (target) which will be given to the callback as the first parameter (some kind of workaround for the missing "this" reference).

Registration-Signature

```
AddItem(string s, void(*callback)(void*,MenuItem*), void* target = NULL)
```

Example of a Registration

```
menu->AddItem(TRANSLATE, "translate", &MyApp::OnModeSelected);
```

Example of a Handler

```
/* static */
void MyApp::OnModeSelected(void* that, MenuItem* item) {
    MyApp *self = (MyApp*)that;
    self->activeMode = item->text;
}
```

Is there anything one could consider dirty with this approach? Are there maybe better ones?

Comment: You should not be using static member methods as the callback here. You should only be using functions that are declared extern "C". You just happen to be getting lucky that the compiler you are using uses (currently) uses the same method for calling static methods and functions. This is not guaranteed by the standard.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your approach requires the callback functions to either be free functions or static members of a class. It does not allow clients to use member functions as callbacks. One solution to this is to use [boost::function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/function.html) as the type of the callback:

```
typedef boost::function<void (MenuItem*)> callback_type;
AddItem(const std::string& s, const callback_type& callback = callback_type());
```

Clients can then use [boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/bind/bind.html) or [boost::lambda](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/lambda.html) to pass in the callback:

```
menu->AddItem("Open", boost::bind(&MyClass::Open, this));
```

Another option is to use [boost::signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/signals.html) which allows multiple callbacks to register for the same event.

Comment: I'd use `MenuItem&` but otherwise entirely agreed.

Comment: You should not use static members of the class as a general callback (they do not have a defined ABI). The boost::function is just a generalization of declaring an interface (the boost::function just uses the interface operator() ). I would prefer my interfaces to be a bit more explicit in this case so that you do not pass an inappropriate method back (ie get the compiler to validate the callback) as described by orsogufo

Answer (score 8):

I like your approach. One alternative would be to declare an interface, which is in some sense the "OO equivalent" of a callback:

```
class IMenuEntry {
public:
    virtual void OnMenuEntrySelected(MenuItem* item) = 0;
};
```

The registration signature would become

```
AddItem(string s, IMenuEntry * entry);
```

And the method implementation

```
class MyApp : public IMenuEntry {
public:
    virtual void OnMenuEntrySelected(MenuItem* item){
        activeMode = item->text;
    }
}
```

The interface approach would allow you to avoid the "void * workaround" for the missing `this` pointer.

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at using [boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/bind/bind.html).

```
menu->AddItem(TRANSLATE, 
              "translate", 
              boost::bind( &MyApp::OnModeSelected, this, _1, _2 ));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong except that the function pointer signature is  hard to read. But, I would probably [observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend looking at [boost::function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/function.html) and [boost:bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/bind/bind.html) for this. Learning it will make your function binding a hundred times easier.

Comment: also, don't forget boost::lambda. It can sometimes let you away without a callback altogether!

Comment: boost::signals is better for this task.

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](http://www.newty.de/jakubik/callback.html) white-paper. It builds various techniques for a callback mechanism by analysing the performance, usability and other tradeoffs in quite a detail. I found it a hard read though :-(

Answer (score 0):

Your could use a [functor](http://www.newty.de/fpt/functor.html) to encapsulate your callback. This would allow you to use either a C-style function or an object interface to provide the callback.